# Linking to Correct Team Services Account

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a personal and a business VSTS accounts.
When I attempt to link my azure account subscription it will only link to my personal VSTS account and not to my business VSTS account.
The VSTS is business account was created by my partner but I am an administrator.

My goal is to setup automated builds and deployments but this account issue is stumbling block.

I attempt to follow two different methods both failed.

1. I used the steps outlined here:
   https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Setting-up-a-VSTS-account-so-it-can-deploy-to-a-Web-App  (Go to the Team Services Account)
   This resulted in the issue above.  The linked account is my personal and not my business and there seems to be no way to change it.
2. I tried the method outlined here:
   https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps
   But this resulted in the account not being authorized (generic auth error) when selecting the subscription.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that linking Azure Subscriptions to VSTS is for billing purposes only.  In order to do this, you need to be the owner of the VSTS account (there can only be one) and also a co-administrator as per [this link.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/set-up-billing-for-your-account-vs)  You can switch the owner by following the instructions [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/change-account-ownership-vs).

If you want to setup VSTS for automated build/release into Azure, what you want to do is setup an Azure Service Endpoint.  The steps are essentially to setup an Azure service account (see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal)) and then to create the service endpoint in VSTS release (see [this link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/service-endpoints)).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this article to unlink and relink account: [Change the Azure subscription your Team Services account uses for billing](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/set-up-billing-for-your-account-vs#change-azure-subscription).

If you just need to deploy app to azure, you don’t need to link account, just [add Azure Service Endpoint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/04/automating-azure-resource-group-deployment-using-a-service-principal-in-visual-studio-online-buildrelease-management/) and deploy app by using [Azure App Service Deploy step/task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment).