# How to move resources from a Personal Azure BizSpark Account to an Organizational Account

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, bizspark, azure-artifacts

My firm was accepted to Microsoft BizSpark and the initial Azure accounts a few of us set up were personal accounts to make use of the free Azure dollars. Now we want to move some resources from the personal accounts to the firm's organizational account with the least amount of changes and downtime. The resources in particular that standout are the VSTS items (sprint board, build definitions, and Git repos). I would like to move all of them to the organizational account without changing the resources. I don't care about moving the free credits of the BizSpark account.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528845/linking-to-correct-team-services-account/43530386#43530386 help?  VSTS linking with Azure is only for billing, not for authentication.

Comment: Do you check these articles: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/change-account-ownership-vs and https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/change-azure-active-directory-team-services-account

Comment: @CtrlDot Unfortunately I need to move authentication and billing and that process didn't work due to the fact that I was trying to transfer a BizSpark account to an Organizational account on Azure

Comment: @starain-MSFT Unfortunately it didn't let accept the transfer requested because my email address has both an org account and a personal azure account associated with it. Azure thinks I'm trying to accept with my personal account and not my organizational account

Comment: How do you configure your VSTS account before? Create the VSTS account and then link to BizSpark Azure Account?